# how to add solid line between word or sentence? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to add these lines between words/sentences as I saw many of solution involve the `border-bottom-line` or `js`. I was just curious that can these lines be done simply just using a `span` or `div`(containing line and sentence) or something else. I've try but I wonder there is way that is better than mine.

[click to see image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dN0h.png)

```css
.ll{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="ll">
  <span> one </span>
  <span>-</span>
  <span> two </span>
  <span>-<span>
  <span> three </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't get an arbitrary long line with the character "-". That's why CSS border is used.

Comment: that helps!, tysm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with `pseudo elements`.

```css
.ll{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
span:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 4px;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
span:last-child:after{
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ll">
  <span> one </span>
  <span> two </span>
  <span> three </span>
</div>
```